# Importing OGR from OSGEO Issues

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

I am trying to run:

```
from osgeo import ogr
```

and I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    from osgeo import ogr
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 21, in 
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 13, in swig_import_helper
    import _gdal
ImportError: No module named _gdal

So obviously, it's finding the osgeo mod, but what the heck is the _gdal mod? A simple search within my Python paths, shows that I have a module called gdal, but not one with the underscore. Seems like a small issue?

Comment: You need to include the path to your OSGEO install somewhere. Try *import sys* then *sys.path.append(Path_to_install)* prior to *from osgeo import gdal*.

Comment: look into this directory (if it exists) just for fun: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo

Comment: In my C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo location theres a 'gdal' file but it's not the '_gdal' one that the error throws. And "'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\lib\\site-packages'" is within my sys.path and that's where the osgeo folder is. So python already is pointed to it.

Comment: curious if you solved this. was gdal installed as standalone or with a python distro (anaconda, xy, etc..)?

Comment: I'm interested: Could you solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Please have a read of the welcome guide to familiarize how to best use this site.  If your having a particular issue start a question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today as I was trying to install GDAL on a new machine. I got the error above after the install appeared to work and I was trying to start using it.

The best solution turned out to be starting again and installing from Christoph Gohlke's unofficial binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal